# Method with Var Method input?

Tags: c#

In C#:

Is it possible define a method that **input parameter** is any **method**?

Let me better description:

I want a method with signature

```
bool IsDoit(var method)
{
    try
    {
        method(...);
        return true;
    }
    catch{return false;}
}
```

This get a method and return a boolean that is throw exception or not!

Generic Delegate? Generic Action? Generic Func?

Do You have any idea or it is **not possible**?

Comment: Instead of bool, return Exception object is better idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What would go in the "..." here? It sounds like you want a delegate of some description - and that delegate signature should match the one of the method you want to call. For example:

```
static bool IsDoit(Action method)
{
    try
    {
        method();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That will allow method group conversions for any parameterless void method:

```
if (IsDoIt(SomeMethodWithNoParameters))
{
}
```

If the caller wants to call a method which takes other parameters, they can use a lambda expression to wrap it in an `Action`:

```
if (IsDoIt(() => MethodWithParameters("first", "second"))
{
}
```

Personally I'm not at *all* sure about the wisdom of this design in the first place, mind you - catching exceptions and swallowing them without any sort of logging seems like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: I Agree with you about catching exceptions and swallowing them.Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @RedHat: Except that `Exception` is already a reference type, so you can't write `Nullable<Exception>`. But I'd still *usually* discourage this; the idiomatic way of handling exceptions is for them to be thrown rather than returned. There may be *some* cases where it's appropriate, but I'd suggest they're pretty rare.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for parameterless methods, replace `var` with `Action`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your method as delegate for example using action:

```
bool IsDoit(Action test)
{
   test(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always accept a generic delegate. Delegates all derive from [System.Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public delegate R Deleg1<R,T1>(T1 arg);
    public delegate R Deleg2<R,T1,T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);
    public delegate R Deleg3<R,T1,T2,T3>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3);

    public static void AcceptAny<R,T1>(Deleg1<R,T1> del) {  /**/ }
    public static void AcceptAny<R,T1,T2>(Deleg2<R,T1,T2> del) {  /**/ }
    public static void AcceptAny<R,T1,T2,T3>(Deleg3<R,T1,T2,T3> del) {  /**/ }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

If you don't mind a little type erase, you can

```
public delegate R DelegParams<R>(params object[] @params);
public static void AcceptAny<R>(DelegParams<R> paramsFunc) {  /**/ }
```

You can *indirectly* assign most any delegate to this signature by using a lambda expression to wrap it (much like the `Action` approach shown by Jon Skeet).

Note that delegates share a common base class and allow you to invoke them using 'reflection-like' interfaces (taking generic `object[]` as params, e.g.): **[Delegate.DynamicInvoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx)**